# Chi-Squared test or another? 16 subjects, 133 comments divided into 2 dichotomous categories

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I have  16 subjects that rated and commented on two essays (essay 1 and essay 2). I have categorized the comments into 2 dichotomous categories: 1. Non-vocabulary VS Vocabulary comments (basically comments that address the vocabulary used VS comments that address everything else) and 2. Positive VS Negative comments.

What test do I use to see if one essay received more/less comments in one of the categories compared to the other? For example, did Essay 1 have significantly more negative/positive comments than Essay 2? Did Essay 1 have significantly less comments on Vocabulary than Essay 2?

I feel I should use a Chi-Squared Test for both, however does my study violate the test of independence? I have a 133 comments total divided into each of the dichotomous categories, but there are only 16 subjects. I read that for the Chi-Squared Test only one subject can contribute to one data point.

If not the Chi-Squared test, what other test should I use? I don't think the McNemar test makes sense for my data.

Thanks